# Modifying the histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, axes

I have the following histogram which I have obtained using `hist` in `MATLAB`.

[image]

The issue here is that where the range is `0-250` on the `y-axis`, I want that to be on the `x-axis`, and vice versa.

How can this be done in MATLAB?

Thanks.

Comment: Just swap `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[n, xout] = hist(rand(1,100)); barh(xout,n)